# how to position name of each step up and below the counter?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

this is the code of the multip-step form navigator which displays all the steps. each step has a step number in a circle and a name below the step number. I want it in an alternative way. For one-step name should be below the step number and for the next step the step name should be at the top of the step number and so on till the last step.

I am also attaching an image of how it looks
[image]

```
     <div class="form-wizard-header">
                        <div class="stepper-wrapper">
                            <div class="stepper-item  @if(empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) || $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_one') active @endif" onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_one',this)" id="pedigree_bar">
                              <div class="step-counter">1</div>
                              <div class="step-name mt-3" >My Pedigree Info</div>
                            </div>
                            <div  class="stepper-item  @if(!empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) && $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_two') active @endif"  onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_two',this)"  id="find_me_here_bar">
                              <div class="step-name" style="paddinf-top:-50px">Find Me Here</div>
                              <div class="step-counter">2</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="stepper-item @if(!empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) && $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_three') active @endif" onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_three',this)" id="gender_identity_bar">
                              <div class="step-counter">3</div>
                              <div class="step-name mt-3" >Gender Identity Information</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="stepper-item @if(!empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) && $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_four') active @endif"  onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_four',this)" id="enthnicity_bar">
                              <div class="step-counter">4</div>
                              <div class="step-name mt-3" >Ethnicity Information</div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="stepper-item @if(!empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) && $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_five') active @endif" onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_five',this)" id="neighborhood_bar">
                                <div class="step-counter" >5</div>
                                <div class="step-name mt-3" >My Neighborhood is</div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="stepper-item @if(!empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) && $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_six') active @endif" onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_six',this)" id="employment_bar">
                                <div class="step-counter">6</div>
                                <div class="step-name mt-3" >Employment Information</div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="stepper-item @if(!empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) && $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_seven') active @endif" onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_seven',this)" id="protect_cards_bar">
                                <div class="step-counter">7</div>
                                <div class="step-name mt-3" >Protect These Charge Cards</div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="stepper-item @if(!empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) && $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_eight') active @endif" onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_eight',this)" id="facial_image_upload_bar">
                                <div class="step-counter">8</div>
                                <div class="step-name mt-3" >Facial Image Upload</div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="stepper-item @if(!empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) && $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_nine') active @endif" onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_nine',this)" id="head_n_face_bar">
                                <div class="step-counter">9</div>
                                <div class="step-name mt-3" >Head & Face Info</div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="stepper-item @if(!empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) && $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_ten') active @endif" onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_ten',this)" id="hair_bar">
                                <div class="step-counter">10</div>
                                <div class="step-name mt-3" >Hair</div>
                              </div>

                              
                              <div class="stepper-item @if(!empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) && $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_eleven') active @endif" onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_eleven',this)" id="distinguish_bar">
                                <div class="step-counter">11</div>
                                <div class="step-name mt-3" >Distinguishing Identifiers</div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="stepper-item @if(!empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) && $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_twelve') active @endif" onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_twelve',this)" id="twin_identifier_bar">
                                <div class="step-counter">12</div>
                                <div class="step-name mt-3" >Twin Identifier</div>
                              </div>
                              {{-- <div class="stepper-item @if(!empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) && $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_thirteen') active @endif" onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_thirteen',this)" id="open_bar">
                                <div class="step-counter">13</div>
                                <div class="step-name mt-3" >Open</div>
                              </div> --}}
                              <div class="stepper-item @if(!empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) && $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_fourteen') active @endif" onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_fourteen',this)" id="medical_info_bar">
                                <div class="step-counter">14</div>
                                <div class="step-name mt-3" >Medical Info</div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="stepper-item @if(!empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) && $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_fifteen') active @endif" onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_fifteen',this)" id="family_history_bar">
                                <div class="step-counter">15</div>
                                <div class="step-name mt-3" >Family & Medical History</div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="stepper-item @if(!empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) && $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_sixteen') active @endif" onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_sixteen',this)" id="travel_info_bar">
                                <div class="step-counter">16</div>
                                <div class="step-name mt-3" >Special Licenses</div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="stepper-item @if(!empty($this_is_me_return_back_data) && $this_is_me_return_back_data->fieldset_id == 'fieldset_seventeen') active @endif" onclick="switchFieldset('fieldset_seventeen',this)" id="attestation_bar">
                                <div class="step-counter">17</div>
                                <div class="step-name mt-3" >Attestation</div>
                              </div>

                             
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Css

```
<style>
    .stepper-wrapper {
  margin-top: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.stepper-item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  cursor: pointer;

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

.stepper-item::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  top: 20px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.stepper-item::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.stepper-item .step-counter {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.stepper-item.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.stepper-item.completed .step-counter {
  background-color: #4bb543;
}

.stepper-item.completed::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 2px solid #4bb543;
  width: 100%;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.stepper-item:first-child::before {
  content: none;
}
.stepper-item:last-child::after {
  content: none;
}
.permanent_color{
  color:skyblue;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

its so simple. u can use loop through all the elements while comparing their index is odd or even. if even title comes under otherwise title comes over.

logic: use common `className` for each parent element. use `querySelectorALl` to select all element. change children's order by index number

try this

```
<script>
let stepperwrappers = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll(".stepper-wrapper")
);
stepperwrappers.forEach((block, i) => {
    let img = block.children[0].innerHTML,
        title = block.children[1].innerHTML;
    i % 2 == 0
        ? ((block.children[0].innerHTML = title),
          (block.children[1].innerHTML = img))
        : ((block.children[1].innerHTML = title),
          (block.children[0].innerHTML = img));
});</script>
```